# Difficulty in proving arbitrary algebra is isomorphic to quaternion algebra, C or R.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm proving finite rank $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$ without zero factor is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{C}$ or quaternion algebra. Framework for this proof is as follow:

Step 1: if $\alpha\in A-\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}[\alpha]\simeq\mathbb{C}$.
This step is easy, just solving the equation for $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is enough.

Step 2: if $\beta\in A-\mathbb{R}[\alpha]$, pick $i\in\mathbb{R}[\alpha],j\in\mathbb{R}[\beta]$ such that $i^2=j^2=-1$, and prove that $ij+ji=0$.

Considering $ji+ij$ is commutative to $i,j$, we can prove $ij+ji\in\mathbb{R}$ by contradiction, but it difficult to prove $ij+ji=0$. I'm considering prove $(i+j)^2=(i-j)^2$.

Step 3: Prove $\mathbb{R}[\alpha,\beta]=A$.

Well, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm proving finite rank ℝ-algebra  without zero factor is isomorphic to ℝ,ℂ or quaternion algebra.

You're proving finite dimensional ℝ-algebra  without (nonzero) zero divisors is isomorphic to ℝ,ℂ or quaternion algebra $\mathbb H$.  In other words, you are proving the [Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)).

> This step is easy, just solving the equation for $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is enough.

I think a reader is not going to know what you mean, although I think this does point the way to a proof.  Certainly $A$ contains $\mathbb R[\alpha]$, which (if you have the fundamental theorem of algebra for $\mathbb R$ says its a field extension of degree $2$, and you can argue it's a copy of $\mathbb C$ with a little work.

> if $\beta\in A-\mathbb{R}[\alpha]$, pick $i\in\mathbb{R}[\alpha],j\in\mathbb{R}[\beta]$ such that $i^2=j^2=-1$,

How do you know you can do any of that?  You should explain.

If you examine [other proofs of the Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)#Proof), you will be able to tell that details are needed.